# Torque profile with fixed boundary condition

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, models

I am trying to find a simple treatment of elasticity theory of a scenario where I have a thin rod attached to a disc (radius $r_0$), and the disc is held fixed at its edge. Now I apply some torque to the (rigid) rod. I expect that the disc while twist around the axis of the rod, leading to some twisting angle $\theta(r)$ as a function of the radial coordinate. By the boundary condition, I expect $\theta(r=r_0)=0$.

Is there a term to what is happening to the disc here? Can we calculate $\theta(r)$ (in a simplified fashion)? What microscopic parameters enter here?

Comment: Consider to include a diagram.